# How do building setbacks work on corners of the section?

Tags: building-regulations

Say that local regulations prohibit building within 10' (3 m) of a side boundary. And say that my side boundary has an internal corner as shown in the attached image. When determining how close I may build to a corner, can I simply measure 10' (3 m) from the nearest part of the boundary? Or do I need to extend the setbacks on the adjacent sides. It's clearer to explain visually. I think the attached image explains my question better.

[image]

Comment: I think it will depend on your local building department if they allow it to be curved.  Some will take the easy way and say no, since straight lines are easier to measure.  I am too lazy to do the math but looks to only be a foot or two gain/lost.  Bringing coffee and donuts to them when you ask, might get a better answer if you want that section.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question of [Local building codes or advice limited to your area](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and therefore off-topic.

Comment: Not just a matter of local code, but of the _specific inspector_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save yourself the trouble of wondering: contact your authority having jurisdiction, and ask them exactly this question.

Answer (score 4):

Asking the building authorities is the way to go.   If you have a definitive need to use that area for your construction you can petition the authorities for a Variance.  The procedure for that will have to come from the same authorities.